# Error message "Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '}'"

Tags: c#, razor

I have this piece of code which gives me the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '}'

The error indicates the closing braces in line 69:

```
Line 67:              @ibItem.ToString()
Line 68:              @ibCount++
Line 69:          }
Line 70:      </div>
Line 71:      <!-- Carousel nav -->
```

Code:

```
@{int ibCount = 0;}
@foreach (var ibItem in Model.imagePath)
{
       @ibItem.ToString()
       @ibCount++
}
```

Can I solve the issue?

Comment: Sometime this kind of error come from other part in the code, check carefully your matching brackets

Comment: More info: When I remove "@ibCount++" from the code, it loads. If I add "@ibCount++;" (with ';') it gives an error "CS1525: Invalid expression term ';'" (indicates Line 68:  @ibCount++; in red) . Thanks.

Comment: Try to post more complete code, it seems like there is mismatching somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to print the ibItem to the view and increment ibCount. In this case, the @ symbol is not necessary as you're into the *foreach* loop and you haven't written any markup, so Razor thinks it is still inside a "code" statement, so the @ is redundant. Of course, since now ibCount is code, you need the semicolon at the end of the line.

```
@{int ibCount = 0;}
@foreach (var ibItem in Model.imagePath)
{
   ibCount++;
   @ibItem.ToString()
}
```

If you instead want to write the count too, I'd suggest to do the following (cover the value with brackets):

```
@{int ibCount = 0;}
@foreach (var ibItem in Model.imagePath)
{
   @ibItem.ToString()
   @(ibCount++)
}
```

A good reference is *[C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)*.

Comment: That helped! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing semicolons. It points to the end brace because that character is invalid. It needs to be either another component of an expression or the end of an expression.

```
@{int ibCount = 0;}
@foreach (var ibItem in Model.imagePath)
{
       @ibItem.ToString();
       @ibCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar issue during the `Web.config` transformation.

I am getting this error:

```
Severity  Code    Description                      Project         File                                                                                                            Line  Suppression  State
**Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term '<'**    AgencyAdmin2    C:\AcuityBrandAllcode\AgencyAdmin2\as-con-agencyadmin2\src\AgencyAdmin2\AgencyAdmin2\Web.Dev.Compiled.config    1     Active.
```

I have resolved this issue by going to properties and changing *Build Action* to *Content*:

[image: Option]